# Is there any event to recognize Scrollbar click

Tags: javascript

Is there any event that will be raised on scrollbar click.

my requirement is once i click or start dragging the horizontal scrollbar sometask i need to perform.Can anybobody plz let me know which javascript event suits my requirement.

Comment: There's no direct event for that, although you might listen to the `scroll` event. This is implemented different across browsers. Some fire it continuously, while others upon completion.

Answer (score 0):

The closest you'll get is

```
document.onscroll = function(){alert("you scrolled");}
```

or in jQuery

```
$(document).scroll(function(){alert("you scrolled");});
```

Different browsers handle it in different ways, generally they fire everytime the page moves a pixel or more. In Android browsers it only updates when you stop scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

In Firefox 29, this works within a mousedown event (true if scrollbar was clicked):

```
if (e.explicitOriginalTarget.tagName === 'HTML')
```